# I need a regex to return true for 01.mp4

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to sort out specific files depending on their names, i want a regex that returns true for file names like : 01.mp4, 99.avi, 05.mpg.

the file extensions must match exactly to the ones that i want and the filename must start with characters which can not be longer than 2 characters. the first part is done but the file extensions aren't working. need some help 
the regex that I have is

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}\.[mp4|mpg|avi]*/
```

but it also returns true for 01.4mp4, 01.4mp4m.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}\.(?:mp4|mpg|avi)$/
```

Comment: can you tell me what does ?: do here, i what i think is that is somehow limits the characters of extension

Comment: To explain: the square brackets, `[]`, denote a character class; `[abc]` means "match either `a` or `b` or `c`", and `[a-z]` means "match any character between `a` and `z`".  Thus, `[mp4|mpg|avi]` matches *any of those characters*, the order being irrelevant.  Parentheses, `()`, group regular expressions, which is what you want to do.  The `?:` bit tells the regex engine not to allocate a capturing group for that set of parentheses, otherwise it would be accessible with `$1`.

Comment: oh alright, if I am not wrong then this simply means that () match exactly whats given, while having ?: or not wont matter that much

Comment: Yes, in a way; you get a slight performance benefit if you use `(?:...)`, and it might help later on in regexes where you have several capturing groups and several non-capturing groups to keep the numbering of backreferences simple. Apart from that, `(...)` will match exactly the same as `(?:...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with my original regex and came up with this

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}\.[mp4|mpg|avi]{3}$/
```

and this works like a charm :)

Answer (score -2):

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}\.[mp4|mpg|avi]?/
```

Comment: That would make the extension optional (but non repeating), but it wouldn't solve the original problem.

Comment: How is it different from OP's regex and how does it solve the problem - you're confused between parenthetic groups `()` and character class `[]`